# Problem in R: extracting dates from tibble - works when directly addressed, but not by reference. Any ideas?

Tags: r

I am endeavouring to extract dates from a tibble. The dataset contains (among other things) country names, dates, and data on (coronavirus) cases.

My goal is to extract the dates at which in a given country a threshold is crossed (say 1000 cases).

My problem: I can do that if I address the country directly; but when I put the country ISO codes into a vector and address them in that way (in order to loop over it), it does not.

I have wrecked my brain in vain and hope for cleverer minds here (I am not a programmer ;-).

Here is some code to illustrate it:

`temp <- first(select(filter(EU28_tidycovid19, iso3c == "SWE", confirmed >= 1000), date)[[1]])`

results in

`[1] "2020-03-15"`

But when I put it like this:

`temp <- first(select(filter(EU28_tidycovid19, iso3c == country, confirmed >= 1000), date)[[1]])`

even though `country` is `[1] "SWE"`, the output of `temp` is

`[1] NA` (when I would expect a date).

Any ideas what produces the difference in behaviour?
Most greateful for any ideas!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a **minimal** dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)).  These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: Do you happen to have a `country` column in your `EU28_tidycovid19` data frame? Without a reproducible example, we can only guess ...

Comment: Valeri, you are absolutely right! That is the problem. Changing the naming of the counter with which I wanted to loop over the EU28 country ISO codes solved the problem. Lazy thinking, lazy naming on my part... Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks to Valeri Voev for pointing out that there was a problem with a variable contained in te data frame. That led to the confusion - and renaming it solved the problem!